# How to use a range, from another workbook, in a formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm automating a large number of emails which deliver KPIs and backing data to managers on a daily basis.

How do I get NETWORKDAYS(startdates, enddates, *holidays*) to use the range *holidays* on another Excel workbook?

The whole process is:

1. Task scheduler opens an XLSM file daily.
2. The XLSM file opens a csv output, edits and analyses it - including using NETWORKDAYS.
3. The csv file is then emailed out, with an email that reports the KPI it calculates.

I want to make sure *holidays* is kept on one Excel workbook only, separate from the xlsm files, because there are going to be many such xlsm files scheduled - if holiday dates change, I only want to have to update one range.

I have tried a number of things using with, set, named ranges. (I've only used VBA for a few days, so may be missing something obvious, however.)

```
Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MAX(NETWORKDAYS([@[Effective Requested Date]], [@[Scheduled Date]], holidays), NETWORKDAYS([@[Effective Requested Date]], [@ExamDate], holidays))"
```

My NETWORKDAYS column outputs as #VALUE. I am expecting the output to be a whole number.

Comment: You should need to include the workbook name & table name in the formula. Can you try building such a formula manually (via point & click in Excel, for instance) and then compare versus the formula you're currently using? It should be easy to spot the difference in syntax.

Comment: Hi David, I did that yesterday. It worked in that session. But when the macro ran today, it asked me to update the file location of the holidays file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you include the exact prompt/message that you get from that attempt? Has the file location changed?

Comment: Hi David, I'll try to recreate the error. When I copy and paste from the XLSM file, the code changes to    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MAX(NETWORKDAYS([@[Effective Requested Date]], [@[Scheduled Date]], holidays.xlsx!HolidaysTable[holidays]), NETWORKDAYS([@[Effective Requested Date]], [@ExamDate], holidays.xlsx!HolidaysTable[holidays]))". <p> This produces an #REF

Comment: That formula is valid when you do it manually, right? Like it returns a value? But it is giving you the #REF when made from VBA?

Comment: Correct. I can copy and paste it and it works. I've just tried the macro when holidays.xlsx is open - the macro works when that file is open. However, is holidays.xlsx is not open, the macro doesn't open. I wonder if a solution then is to have the macro open the holidays file...

Comment: OK, so if you *close* the holidays file, you'll see that the formulas will change as a result. I believe they will include the full file path and the filename in square brackets, something like `"C:\path\to\my\files\[holidays.xlsx]"`. I think that is how you need to implement.

Comment: Yes - it did change. It changed to 'C:\Users\TChivs\Desktop\Macro\holidays.xlsx'!HolidaysTable[holidays] However, if I copy and paste that into the macro, the #REF error returns.

Comment: Okay, so I have this working provided the file with the holidays is open when the csv is analyzed, and open when the emailed file is open. So I think I will now try to solve this problem by copy and pasting the data as plain text, so the formula no longer looks to the other file.

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks for your help. I am very new to this, but find it very rewarding. Perhaps when I am more advanced, I will be able to give back to the community in the way you clearly do.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an [explicit limitation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) of using structured references to external `ListObject` tables in a formula string.

> **Use workbooks with external links to Excel tables in other workbooks**    If a workbook contains an external link to an Excel table in another workbook, that linked source workbook must be open in Excel to avoid #REF! errors in the destination workbook that contains the links. If you open the destination workbook first and #REF! errors appear, they will be resolved if you then open the source workbook. If you open the source workbook first, you should see no error codes.

One way around this would be to **not** use structured references, and instead refer to the range's absolute address instead, assuming the sheet name is "HolidaysTable", or modify as needed:

```
C:\Users\TChivs\Desktop\Macro\[holidays.xlsx]HolidaysTable!$A$2:$A:$20
```

Alternatively, since it seems you're producing a CSV with these computations, it would be better to simply produce the calculation on the VBA side (i.e., *not* in a worksheet formula, that is subsequently destroyed into its Value only, when saving as a CSV), I think I would take a slightly different approach to your application design:

Instead of opening one of many XLSM files that do (the same?) something, use only ONE .xlsm file that contains the holiday information and whatever other macro/VBA code you need. Now, as for the "many" XLSM files, each of these should be given as a parameter to each respective scheduled task, so you'd have something like

1. Task1 = Opens main.xlsm with parameter "C:\pathto\bar.xlsm"
2. Task2 = Opens main.xlsm with parameter "C:\pathto\foo.xlsm"
3. Task3 = Opens main.xlsm with parameter "C:\pathto\another.xlsm"

In this way, you have all of the code & holidays & etc in a single source ("main.xlsm") which does something(s) with the other files as scheduled via task manager.